# Missing X-Spam-Status header

Tags: postfix, mail

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (trusty) and have followed the directions in https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/mail-filtering.html and am sending and receiving mail just fine.

While I do see `X-Virus-Scanned` headers in my messages, which suggests mail is indeed being processed, I do not see any `X-Spam-Level` or `X-Spam-Score` headers being added to messages. This makes downstream `procmailrc` and client-side filtering ...more difficult.

While having `$final_spam_destiny = D_DISCARD` in /etc/amavis/conf.d/20-debian_defaults does greatly reduce spam to my inbox, I had concerns of false-positives prior to tuning and didn't know were there going, so have set it to `D_PASS` for the time being.  This exposed the problem.

I'm not sure where to look to start diagnosing the problem (otherwise I'd post a suspect configuration file).

/etc/amavis/conf.d/15-content_filter_mode has the lines *uncommented* to enable virus and spam checks, and virus checking appears to be working according to the headers.

Spam Assassin certainly seems to be starting just fine, too.

> SpamAssassin debug facilities: info
>   SA info: zoom: able to use 360/360 'body_0' compiled rules (100%)
>   SpamAssassin loaded plugins: AskDNS,
>   AutoLearnThreshold, Bayes, BodyEval, Check, DKIM, DNSEval, FreeMail,
>   HTMLEval, HTTPSMismatch, Hashcash, HeaderEval, ImageInfo, MIMEEval,
>   MIMEHeader, Pyzor, Razor2, RelayEval, ReplaceTags, Rule2XSBody, SPF,
>   SpamCop, URIDNSBL, URIDetail, URIEval, VBounce, WLBLEval,
>   WhiteListSubject
>   SpamControl: init_pre_fork on SpamAssassin done

I've also set `$log_level = 2;` in /etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user and don't see any obvious errors rolling by in the logs.

Q: Any recommendations of what to try next?

UPDATE (it appears that I have the right setting already):

```
/etc/amavis/conf.d$ grep sa_tag_level_deflt *
20-debian_defaults:# $sa_tag_level_deflt  = 2.0;  # add spam info headers if at, or above that level
20-debian_defaults:$sa_tag_level_deflt  = -999;  # add spam info headers if at, or above that level
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, problem solved, and it was a conglomeration of things, which I'll detail here for others finding themselves down the same path.

First of all, [spamassassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org) appears to have issues (in some environments) running with ipv6.  Dunno why. Edit `/etc/default/spamassassin`, or `/etc/init.d/spamassassin` if you don't have one, and add `--ipv4` to the `OPTIONS` list.  Then use `service spamassassin restart` to bounce the service, and `service spamassassin status` to check that spamd is running. This step may not be necessary for your configuration.

Next, make sure that you have an `/etc/procmailrc` file, that it's permissions are world readable, and that it contains something like this:

```
DROPPRIVS=yes
:0fw
| /usr/bin/spamc
:0
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
$HOME/mail/possible-spam
```

Next, if you're running [webmin](http://www.webmin.com) you'll want to check the procmail service, and make sure it's not issuing you a warning that [postfix](http://www.postfix.org) is not configured to use [procmail](http://www.procmail.org).  In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, you'll want to comment out the default `mailbox_command` to run deliver and replace it with procmail.  You'll need to run `service postfix restart` after making the edit.

```
#mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
```

If you've been manually moving your spam messages into a mail folder called `spam`, then you want to train spam assassin like this:

```
sa-learn --progress  --dbpath ~/.spamassassin --spam --mbox ~/mail/spam
```

Note that some further tuning can be done, and it will require doing a `service spam assassin restart` afterward, but this can help.

One, in `/etc/spamassassin/local.cf`, set the `required_score` to a slightly lower value if you get lots of spam:

```
#   Set the threshold at which a message is considered spam (default: 5.0)
#
required_score 4.0
```

In the same file, `/etc/spamassassin/local.cf`, it is also possible to filter by spam-heavy countries by adding this at the end. Here's Russia and China, two very heavy contributors historically speaking based on some email analysis.

```
# Filter Russia
header RELAYCOUNTRY_RU X-Relay-Countries =~ /RU/
describe RELAYCOUNTRY_RU Relayed through Russia
score RELAYCOUNTRY_RU 8.0

# Filter China
header RELAYCOUNTRY_CN X-Relay-Countries =~ /CN/
describe RELAYCOUNTRY_CN Relayed through China
score RELAYCOUNTRY_CN 8.0

report_header 1
fold_headers 1
detailed_phrase_score 1
```

The above not only solved the missing header, which I suspect was the procmail not getting invoked.

Answer (score 3):

`/etc/amavis/conf.d/20-debian_defaults` http://pastebin.com/5xuvNVtD

Change line 36 to something like this:

`$sa_tag_level_deflt  = -999;  # add spam info headers if at, or above that level`

After saving and restarting of the service or reloading the configuration, all the emails should have the x-spam-status header.

Comment: It appears I already have that done.  Bounced the service.  Still, no headers.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: @WaltStoneburner Which command did you use?

Comment: Bounced the a mavis, dovecot, and postfix services... just because.  I got a message tagged as spam and it had the header -- so now I'm convinced it's working (thank you), and my new problem is that it's just not catching a whole lot yet.  Is there a training phase like spamprobe has?

Comment: maybe this can lead you in the right direction http://xyzzyxyzzy.net/2012/09/15/spamassassin-learning-from-inbox-and-junk-folders/

Comment: I've been trying the edit the last comment (if not to fix the typo).  I used $ sudo service [...] restart, which worked as expected.  I'm currently looking at the sa-learn command, so seeing this resource helps me feel like I'm very much on the right track.  Thanks all.

Comment: Discovered I had a very dated .spamassassin directory (it got neglected when I switch to a different technology), now that I'm back, it couldn't use it.  Used sa-learn, sa-update, and bounced the spam assassin service.

Answer (score 3):

The output of command `head -n 1 /etc/mailname` must be your domain, like `example.com`.

If the output is something like `mail.example.com`, **that's the bug**.

So, you can fix this by changing the file `/etc/amavis/conf.d/05-domain_id`

**Solution #1**

Inside `/etc/amavis/conf.d/05-domain_id`:

Change:

```
    chomp($mydomain = `head -n 1 /etc/mailname`);
```

To:

```
    chomp($mydomain = `hostname -d`);
```

PS: The output of `hostname -d` must be your domain, like `example.com`.

**Simplest solution than ever:**

Inside `/etc/amavis/conf.d/05-domain_id`:

Change:

```
    chomp($mydomain = `head -n 1 /etc/mailname`);
```

To:

```
    $mydomain = "example.com";
```

Comment: Great tip!  My own /etc/mailname file is producing the fully qualified machine name and the hostname -d was correctly producing the domain, so don't know if that was it for my system.  But great advice.